# How can I cast a variable to the type of another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion

I want to be able to cast a variable to the specific type of another. As an example:

```
function convertToType(typevar, var) {
    return (type typevar)var; // I know this doesn't work
}
```

so that convertToType(1, "15") returns 15, convertToType("1", 15) returns "15", convertToType(false, "True") returns true, etc.

To reiterate, I want to be able to dynamically cast variables to the types of other variables.

Is this possible?

Comment: JavaScript is dynamically typed. so there is no need for function to convert.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: here's an even more complete example, with tests (requires Node 6+ or some transpilation to ES5): https://github.com/JaKXz/type-convert

You can use the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof) operator to get the right "casting" function:

```
function convertToTypeOf(typedVar, input) {
  return {
    'string': String.bind(null, input),
    'number': Number.bind(null, input)
    //etc
  }[typeof typedVar]();
}
```

Try it out here: http://jsbin.com/kasomufucu/edit?js,console

I would also suggest looking into [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) for your project.

Comment: No, `typeof` tells you what type of data a variable holds, it doesn't convert between data types.

Comment: Did you look at the jsbin @Quentin?

Comment: Did you put information essential to the understanding of your answer on a third party site instead of in the answer?

Comment: @Quentin updated to be a little clearer. Using jsbin gives everyone a place where they can try the code, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing, when it supplements an answer and isn't essential to understand it. You say *to get the right "casting" function*, but the question gives no indicate that they know what functions exist for that purpose.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't understand the downvote though, it's not like this is incorrect. _"the question gives no indicate that they know what functions exist for that purpose."_ The question's title asks for a way to **cast** a value to another value's type. The asker is clearly looking for the functions which do that. What did you think they were asking for?

Comment: Your initial answer just told them to use `typeof`. That doesn't cast anything. Then you edited it to tell them to use `typeof` to pick a function that will do the casting. That doesn't tell them how to write such a function. Your latest example gives a couple of examples, but is lacking any explanation as to how they work.

Comment: @OfekGila I made a more complete example, I'll edit the post to include it. :)

Comment: @Quentin, sorry for the confusion, I tried to make my question a bit clearer. Thanks for your response, though, but I am well aware of the preexisting casting functions :)

Comment: @JaKXz You just made my day.

Comment: I'm sorry @JaKXz: your code in the answer was so little careful about performance that I felt prompted to write my answer that just switch on the inferred type.  Just talking about your answer here, I didn't look in the github version.

Comment: But a hash lookup is much faster than several if statements. I'm not sure what you mean by poor performance.

Comment: @JaKXz well, if the JS engine can't make simple switch statements based on strings faster than an hash lookup is really their problem. Also consider that in your solution you spend compute resources to build the actual dictionary and the bind operation you perform on each type, even if it's not performing the actual conversion, can't be free. Anyway, I retreat my judgment on performance since is not based on any benchmark. Sorry, I just really prefer to see switch statements everywhere because I think it's semantically better.

Answer (score 5):

```
function convertToType (t, e) {
    return (t.constructor) (e);
}
```

[image: repl demo]

note the first call when we wanted to convert 15 to a Number, we append a dot (.) to the first parameter

Comment: The only problem is that convertToType(false, 'false') also evaluates to true. I think the boolean operator is broken. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: to convert to a boolean false from a string, you need to pass in an empty string like the following: `convertToType (false, '')`

Comment: @OfekGila `(false, 'false')` works okay. It shouldn't return false.

Comment: @OfekGila It is not _broken_, but **working as designed**. Here's the relevant section from ECMA-262: [7.1.2 ToBoolean ( _argument_ )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toboolean). Specifically, _String: If argument is the empty String (its length is zero), return false; otherwise return true._

Answer (score 1):

It follows my version of JaKXz answer that is supposedly more efficient by switching on inferred type. In the case of `number` and `boolean` the conversion is loose: in case of invalid input it will output `NaN` and `false`, respectively. You can work on this by adding your stricter validation and more types.

```js
function convertToTypeOf(typevar, input)
{
  let type = typeof typevar;
  switch(type)
  {
    case "string":
      return String.bind(null, input)();
    case "number":
      return Number.bind(null, input)();
    case "boolean":
      return input == "true" ? true : false;
    default:
      throw "Unsupported type";
  }
}

console.log(convertToTypeOf("string", 1));      // Returns "1"
console.log(convertToTypeOf("string", true));   // Returns "true"
console.log(convertToTypeOf("string", false));  // Returns "false"
console.log(convertToTypeOf(1.2, "1"));         // Returns 1
console.log(convertToTypeOf(1.2, "1.5"));       // Returns 1.5
console.log(convertToTypeOf(true, "false"));    // Returns false
console.log(convertToTypeOf(false, "true"));    // Returns true
console.log(convertToTypeOf(1, "asd"));         // Returns NaN
console.log(convertToTypeOf(true, "asd"));      // Returns false
```