# Can I patch an existing class to extend another class?

Tags: javascript

I have the following class and I cannot change it

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('foo')
  }
}
```

I would like to patch it using a function so that it extends another class (calling `super()` as the first line of it's constructor)

```js
function extendWithBar(TargetCtor) {
  class Bar {
    constructor() {
      console.log('bar')
    }
  }

  //... secret sauce

  // Equivalent of "Foo extends Bar"
  // can extend other classes too
  return TargetExtendingBar
}

// FooBar is a new constructor, it doesn't need to relate to Foo
// it only needs to have the same constructor
const FooBar = extendBar(Foo)

const foobar = new FooBar()
// Output:
// "bar"
// "foo"
```

Is this possible in JavaScript, if so, how?

Comment: Can you just do `class Bar extends Foo` and call super ? or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, `Bar` doesn't know what it's being used to extend. In this case it's `Foo` but it could be any class

Comment: Additionally order is important, I need `Foo` to extend bar, not `Bar` to extend `Foo`

Comment: Can you check if this is helpful to you ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546512/how-can-i-cast-a-variable-to-the-type-of-another-in-javascript

Comment: No, if `Foo` doesn't already `extend` another class, it's not possible to add it in later. You will need to overwrite `Foo` completely.

Comment: I am able to overwrite `Foo` with a `PatchedFoo`, it doesn't need to be the same class, but the constructor must be preserved

Comment: Use typescript with generics than trying to figure it out in JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidAlsh What do you mean by "the constructor must be preserved"?

Comment: Just that it will run the constructor of `Foo` when dynamically extended with `Bar`. So it runs `Bar`'s constructor then `Foo`'s constructor - But it doesn't need to be `Foo` exactly, it can be a clone of `Foo`.

Comment: Right now I am looking into the idea of using `Proxy(Foo, {construct: () => {} })` (Don't need to support IE11)

Comment: @DavidAlsh A proxy won't help.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual problem and show us the actual code of the involved classes (and why you cannot modify them)? Building a class that logs `bar` and then `foo` and overwriting `Foo` by it is easy. What do you really need?

Answer (score 1):

you need to **extends** class1 to class2 like :

```
class class1{
  constructor(let x , let y){
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
  }
}

class class2 extends class1{

 // x & y just arguments for explaining  
 constructor(let x , let y){

   // calling class1 after extends
   super(x , y);
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to result in a situation where I have `class1 extends class2` but `class1` and `class2` don't know about each other. Order matters also where `class2` needs to run before `class1`

Comment: yeah in this case ordering matters so important for code quality & js compiler 
so you need to define parent first & and then the inheritor

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking about reacts Higher Order Components.
ReactJS documentation says:
"Concretely, a higher-order **component** is a **function** that **takes** a **component** and returns a **new component**."
In your case it translates to this:
"a higher-order **class** is a **function** that takes a **class** and returns a **new class**."
**EDIT:** I edited so it can take a class as argument.

```js
class Foo {
      constructor() {
        console.log('foo')
      }
    }


    function withBar(arg){
    return class extends arg{
      constructor(){
        console.log('bar')
        super()
      }
    }
    }

    const fooWithBar = withBar(Foo);
    new fooWithBar()
```

Comment: The order of the output is reversed to what OP has asked.

Comment: This doesn't work - your `withBar` function doesn't even user its argument

Comment: @Ava I think I misunderstood OPs problem, I edited this post so it take an argument as Bergi said.

Comment: I edited again now the super constructor is called after the patcher constructor runs.